# Mean of inverse of sum of squared standard normal variate

Tags: normal-distribution, expected-value, chi-squared

I am working on standard normal distribution and stuck with one derivation.

The problem is I have $10$ independent SNV (standard normal variate) $X_1, X_2,\dots, X_{10}$

What I need to find is Expectation of inverse of sum of squared value these SNV.

$$E\left(\frac{1}{X_1^2+X_2^2+\dots}\right)$$

My views:
I know sum of squared SNV is chi-square, and inverse of which is inv chi square.

Mean of inverse chi square is $1/(\lambda-2)$, where $\lambda 
$ is degrees of freedom of chi square.

So my answer to current question is $1/(10-2)=1/8$ is it correct?
Also, what exact theory is applied here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\dfrac18$ is correct.

You can get from the density of a [chi-squared distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chi-square_distribution) $\frac{2^{-\nu/2}}{\Gamma(\nu/2)}\; x^{\nu/2-1} e^{-x/2}$ to the density of a so-called [inverse chi-squared distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse-chi-squared_distribution) (*reciprocal chi-squared distribution* might be a better name) of $\frac{2^{-\nu/2}}{\Gamma(\nu/2)}\,x^{-\nu/2-1}  e^{-1/(2 x)}$ by standard [change of variables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_density_function#Function_of_random_variables_and_change_of_variables_in_the_probability_density_function): essentially you replace $x$ by $\frac1x$, and multiply by the absolute value of the derivative of the inverse (in its wider meaning), so by $\frac1{x^2}$.

Knowing the density and that it integrates to $1$ makes finding the expectation easy since $x\cdot x^{-\nu/2-1}=x^{-(\nu-2)/2-1}$ and thus  the expectation is $\dfrac{\frac{2^{-\nu/2}}{\Gamma(\nu/2)}}{\frac{2^{-(\nu-2)/2}}{\Gamma((\nu-2)/2)}}=\dfrac{1}{\nu-2}$ when $\nu > 2$, and here $\nu=10$.